# Solving the following differential equation $ y^{(j)}(x) - y^{(j-1)}(x)=\delta(x-1)-e^x-1.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I just found this problem which I'm not sure how to start. I appreciate any hint.
Let $j\in \mathbb{N}$ and $y\in [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$. Solve the differential equation is
$$ y^{(j)}(x) - y^{(j-1)}(x)=\delta(x-1)-e^x-1.$$

The constraints are $y^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n=0,1\dots, j-1$.
How can I find an upper bound $Mj\geq 0$ such that for each $x\in [0,2]$, $|y(x)|<M_j$.